# Como alterar um ícone dentro de uma aplicação react?

Tags: react, icons, styled-components

**Fala guys, tudo joia?**

Estou com uma tremenda dúvida e não faço a mínima ideia de como resolver. Recentemente participei da Semana OmniStack 11 e pude desenvolver uma aplicação do zero, do backend ao frontend e mobile, e hoje (02/04/2020) decidi adicionar um tema escuro na aplicação, esse recurso está funcionando 100%, mas estou com problemas na hora de alterar o ícone que estou utilizando para usar o recurso "tema escuro". **Gostaria de saber como faço para colocar um ícone de "sol(simbolizando o tema claro)" assim que eu clicar na "lua(simbolizando o tema escura)"?**.

Segue o trecho do código que faz a mágica acontecer:

```
import React from 'react';
import {FiSun, FiMoon} from 'react-icons/fi';

import './style.css';

const ThemeSwitcher = ( {toggleTheme} ) => (
  <a onClick={toggleTheme}><FiMoon size={16} color="#343746"/></a>
);
```

Como podem ver no código acima, estou importando dois ícones da biblioteca 'react-icons/fi'. Se atentem também que estou utilizando o "FiMoon" na tag 'a'. Basicamente este código é essencial para que o recurso tema escuro funcione, pois é clicando neste link/ícone que o tema é aplicado.

> O arquivo CSS não contém nada relevante, somente um 'cursor:
>   pointer;'.

Como podem ver na imagem abaixo o ícone de lua está ao lado da logo, e assim que é clicado o tema escuro é aplicado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver o tema foi aplicado mas o ícone da lua sumiu pois está com a mesma cor do background, por isso quero colocar o ícone de sol para simbolizar o tema claro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: Deu certo alguma resposta?

Comment: e se colocar o simbolo alternativo no :hover do escuro e trocar assim que troca o fundo.

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser criado uma variável de estado local do componente e ao clicar no ícone o valor é alterado para aparecer o sol, no seu código precisa então alterar esse mecanismo, um exemplo fora do seu seria assim:

```js
function ChangeIcone({status}) {
  const [ico, setIco] = React.useState(status);  
  return (   
    <div>
      <a 
        onClick={e => setIco(!ico)} 
        href="javascript:;"
        style={{textDecoration:'none', color:'black'}}
      >
       <i 
        class={ico?"zmdi zmdi-image-o":"zmdi zmdi-image"}>
       </i>      
      </a>
    </div>
  )
}
function App() { 
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Clique na ícone</p>
      <hr />
      <ChangeIcone status={true} />
    </div>
  )
 }
 ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-iconic-font/2.2.0/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

exatamente no seu código algo assim:

```
const ThemeSwitcher = ( {toggleTheme, ico} ) => (
  <a onClick={toggleTheme}>
    {ico ? (<FiMoon size={16} color="#343746"/>)
         : (<FiSun size={16})}
  </a>
);
```

sendo a passagem de `props` vindo do componente que o utiliza.

<sup>**Observação:** não coloquei a cor no segundo ícone porque eu não sei visualmente qual seria, e o variável `ico` pode ser `true` ou `false` (`boolean`).</sup>